# Why am I receiving a routing error when the controller method exists, the route is defined and the view calls it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a simple shopping cart application that displays the session's shopping cart with line_items in it on the sidebar of the application layout. I am attempting to add a button at the end of each line item (rendered in _line_item.html.erb) that decrements the quantity in the cart by one using remote: true and some JS. However, when I load the page (before I click anything) I am receiving this routing error from Rails 3.1 in development with no special gems or configurations installed:

```
   Routing Error

    No route matches {:action=>"decrement", :controller=>"line_items"}
```

Here is my method in controllers/line_items_controller.rb, which has been working well for me until now:

```
  def decrement
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.quantity -= 1
    if @line_item.quantity.empty?
      @line_item.destroy
    end 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {@current_item = @line_item}
    end
  end
```

Here is the entry in routes.rb:

```
  resources :line_items do
    member do
      post 'decrement'
    end
  end
```

Here is the code in the partial _line_item.html.erb, which works fine without the button_to link:

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
<tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
    <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
    <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
    <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'Remove one', line_item, decrement_line_item_path, remote: true %></td>
</tr>
```

I must be missing something but I cannot find it. It seems everything is in order to me. What am I doing wrong? Thanks very much.

Edit: here is the error I receive when I use decrement_line_item_path(line_item):

```
ArgumentError in Store#index

Showing /Users/Michael/Sites/rails/depot/app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb where line #9 raised:

wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)
Extracted source (around line #9):

6:  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
7:  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
8:  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
9:  <td><%= button_to 'Remove one', line_item, decrement_line_item_path(line_item), remote: true %></td>
10: </tr>
```

Comment: what do you get when you run rake routes? you don't have to post the whole thing, just the sections relevant to this resource

Comment: decrement_line_item POST   /line_items/:id/decrement(.:format) {:action=>"decrement", :controller=>"line_items"}

Comment: For anybody googling this in the future: This error is also often caused by the request method, GET, PUT, POST, etc. If you are using `get 'posts'`, you will get a "No Route Matches..." error if you try to PUT to posts, for example.

Comment: Yes, I should add also that I only didn't list the method in my button_to because Rails defaults to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decrement_line_item_path` expects an argument for the individual item and you're not giving it one.

Try:

```
<%= button_to 'Remove one', decrement_line_item_path(line_item), remote: true %>
```

Comment: I tried that exactly as you have it and got this error:

ArgumentError in Store#index

Showing /Users/Michael/Sites/rails/depot/app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb where line #9 raised:

wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)
Extracted source (around line #9):

6:  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
7:  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
8:  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
9:  <td><%= button_to 'Remove one', line_item, decrement_line_item_path(line_item), remote: true %></td>
10: </tr>

Comment: I edited the question as code in the comment is difficult to read.

Comment: That's because you haven't used my code, you're still passing line_item as a separate argument.  `button_to` just take `label`, `path`, `options` in that order.  You're passing `line_item` where it should not even be there.

Comment: Oh, I am sincerely sorry. You are right. I didn't see the difference. It works now!